# Is Font Awesome SVG/JS pixel size the Same as CSS/Web Fonts?

Tags: font-awesome

I placed some Font Awesome icons in menu buttons to replace fixed-sized icons. When I do this with the CSS/Web Font approach the icons match the size of the text in the button. When I do it with the SVG/JS approach the buttons with icons are 1px taller. I can't find anything in my CSS that adds the extra pixel. The result is that a row of these menu buttons does not have a consistent height.

My markup is exactly the same in both cases; I use the `<i>` technique.

I can't tell for sure, but it appears the SVG/JS approach is being pushed by the developers (the CSS approach is described as "great ... for older browsers"). I'd like to use it, guessing that it's the future, but I'd really like to avoid redoing my menus if possible.

Has anyone else seen this problem and, if so, how did you resolve it?